# How to add unique classes to FlexSlider slides? (default behavior in v 7.1.x - not in v 7.2.x)

Tags: theming

I just upgraded the flexslider module from 7.1.x to 7.2.x and it broke my styling because the old version gave unique classes to each slide (also odd and even row classes to every other slide), but the new version gives each slide the same classes.

I really need to style each slide differently so I was using these unique classes.

This "feature request" is in the module's [issue queue](https://drupal.org/node/1925624) but it hasn't been touched in a long time and I lack the skills to fix it myself.

Does anyone know how I can give each Flexslider slide a unique class, either using jQuery, PHP or maybe some other module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I was over thinking this. This script will add id 1, 2, 3 etc to my slides. The slides are just list items - I was all intimidated because only one li is visible at a time, but jQuery doesn't care...

```
/*Script for assigning each flexslider slide a unique class*/
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slides li').each(function(i,el){
        el.id = i+1;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start an ID with a number, which means that Anne's jquery will not work. Instead, assign the li a class - in this case, "slide-1", "slide-2", etc...

(having problems figuring out how to type a code block in this answer - what am I missing?)

/* --- Each flexslider slide gets it's own class ---*/
        (function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.slides li').addClass(function(i){
            return "slide-" + (i + 1);
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);